# How do I include one .zig file from another .zig file

Tags: zig

Just exploring Zig... I have one .zig file with a bunch of comptime functions and constants, and I want to use those in other .zig programs. Equivalent to `#include "my.h"` in C.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is that `@import("foo.zig")` *almost* does this. If you had foo.zig:

```
const a = 1;
pub const b = 2;
pub const c = 3;
```

then in main.zig:

```
const stdout = @import("std").io.getStdOut().writer();
const foo = @import("foo.zig");
const c = foo.c;
const a = foo.a;
test "@import" {
//  try stdout.print("a={}\n",.{foo.a});
//  try stdout.print("a={}\n",.{a});
    try stdout.print("b={}\n",.{foo.b});
    try stdout.print("c={}\n",.{c});
}
```

will print the values of b and c but if you uncomment the commented lines, you'll get an error because a wasn't exported (`pub`). Interestingly the `const a=foo.a` doesn't give an error unless `a` is used.

It appears that there is no way to dump all of an import into the current namespace, so if you want the names unqualified, you have to have a `const` line for each.

Thanks to people in the Zig discord, particularly @rimuspp and @kristoff

Comment: Is the extension mandatory or good practice? Without extension, it would feel more "package-style" than file.

Answer (score 5):

You actually can use:

```
const bar = struct {
    usingnamespace @import("foo.zig");
};
```

to import a complete namespace into a struct, but not at the top level.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna import a specific function:

```
pub const foo = @import("foo.zig").foo;
```

If you wanna import a specific `.zig` file:

```
pub const foo = @import("foo.zig");
```